# AlarmManager - How to know if something is scheduled

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager

I'm building an application that uses `AlarmManager` to schedule, upon user request, wifi and bt switch off at a later time.

That works. My next step is to allow the user to cancel.

Naturally, the activity may get killed. Imagine that scenario:

1. User sets the alarm for 30 minutes later
2. User puts phone to sleep, activity is killed
3. User picks up phone and opens app again to cancel the request.

How can I know, inside the newly created activity, that I scheduled something?

Also, I'd like to make a widget for this application, so how could I pass the information from the activity to the widget (and potentially to other elements)?

This is how I setup the alarm:

```
int type = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP; // wake up CPU after said time
long delay = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + minutes * 60 * 1000;
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    // Need to use this method, otherwise Doze is killing us
    manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(type, delay, alarmIntent);
}
else {
    manager.setExact(type, delay, alarmIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel any alarm like this -

Get the pending intent  which is associated with the alarm you want to cancel.

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Then cancel it.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.cancel(alarmIntent);
```